# 5 digit even number and different digits

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a machine that creates different numbers with $5$ digits.
Of course the first digit can't be $0$.

I would like to choose one them, what is the probability that the number is even?

And what is the probability that the number is even and all the digits differ?

My solution for even number: $9* 10 * 10 * 10 * 5!/9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10$
and for even with differ digits: $9 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 5!/9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10$

Comment: Why $4!/9$? and why $4$ not $5$?

Comment: right I changed to 5.(0,2,4,6,8)

Comment: I misread the expression, you mean $(9*10*10*10*5)/(9*10*10*10*10)$. The first is correct except it's $5$ not $5!$. The second expression is more complicated because if some of the previous digits are even, then there is less choice for the last digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression should be $\frac{9*1000*5}{9*10000}$.

The second expression should be $\frac{9*8*7*6+8*8*7*6*4}{90000}$.

If the last digit is $0$ then there are $9*8*7*6$ choices.

If the last digit is one of $2,4,6,8$, then there are $8*8*7*6*4$ choices.